# Pandas - calculate mean and add value in new column

Tags: pandas

I have this df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Players':['John', 'Will', 'John', 'Will', 'John', 'Will'],
                    'Round': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                    'Goals': [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0]})
```

which prints:

```
  Players  Round  Goals
0    John      1      0
1    Will      1      1
2    John      2      1
3    Will      2      1
4    John      3      2
5    Will      3      0
```

Now, how do I keep the same structure, and have the `mean()` calculated round by round for each player, as a new column, ending up with:

```
  Players  Round  Goals   Mean
0    John      1      0   0
1    Will      1      1   1
2    John      2      1   0.5
3    Will      2      1   1
4    John      3      2   1
5    Will      3      0   0.6
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First do this:

```
mean = df.groupby('Players')['Goals'].expanding().mean()
```

It gives you:

```
Players   
John     0    0.000000
         2    0.500000
         4    1.000000
Will     1    1.000000
         3    1.000000
         5    0.666667
Name: Goals, dtype: float64
```

We don't need the `Players` column as part of the index, so remove that:

```
mean.index = mean.index.droplevel(0)
```

And finally assign to the original DataFrame:

```
df['Mean'] = mean
```

The end result is:

```
  Players  Round  Goals      Mean
0    John      1      0  0.000000
1    Will      1      1  1.000000
2    John      2      1  0.500000
3    Will      2      1  1.000000
4    John      3      2  1.000000
5    Will      3      0  0.666667
```

Comment: this answer does not raise the error `TypeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object does not support item assignment`, like the other one does.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, using groupby with `cumsum` and `cumcount`:

```
g=df.groupby(['Players'])['Goals']
df['Mean'] = g.cumsum() / (g.cumcount() + 1)
```

Output:

```
  Players  Round  Goals      Mean
0    John      1      0  0.000000
1    Will      1      1  1.000000
2    John      2      1  0.500000
3    Will      2      1  1.000000
4    John      3      2  1.000000
5    Will      3      0  0.666667
```

Comment: Nice, this is faster than my solution.  And for most people probably easier to understand too.

Comment: I get `TypeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: @8-BitBorges What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: oh, I have `pandas  0.25.3`

Comment: Can you upgrade?  Otherwise, we might have to use transforms in there.

Comment: I'd rather use transforms. upgrading could cause all sorts of changes in my enviroment..

Comment: Try this:  `g.transform('cumsum') / (g.transform('cumcount') + 1)`  Does that work?

Comment: Hrm...  I am not sure where this error is?  Does it work with this test dataset?  I did not get that error in my environment, however I am using pandas 1.0.5 ( I need to upgrade).

Comment: with the test dataset I print an object: `<pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x7fe6e7a647d0>`

Comment: `to_frame()`, maybe?

Comment: oh. you can't print 'g' is a groupby object you need to do some sort of aggregration on g.

Comment: aggreagate what? example?

Comment: OH I must reset index first, no?

Comment: print(g,sum()) or print(g.cumsum()) or somesort of aggregration or apply to that groupby object.